# What does こんな青い空のなか　きっとわたしは　空いろで　風のかたちで　はこばれる mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, song-lyrics, interpretation

I'm translating Japanese novel into my language.

The novel I'm working with now is a fantasy novel about a witch, written for young adult.
There's a song that the witch sings during she's flying in the sky.
The song says

> ひゅーくるるるー
>
> ひゅーくるるるーひゅー
>
> **こんな青い空のなか**
>
> **きっとわたしは　空いろで**
>
> **風のかたちで　はこばれる　はこばれる**
>
> ひゅーくるるるひゅー

If we rewrite this into a normal sentence, should it be "私はきっと空色の風の流れのように運ばれる"? or "空色の風の形に見える私はきっと運ばれる"?

The first translation makes more sense to me, but since it's a song in a fantasy novel, I think I shouldn't judge it by how it sounds rational. Please let me know how you interpret this song. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

風のかたち**で** clearly adverbially modifies 運ばれる, so the literal translation of this part is "I am carried in the form of wind". This is not a common expression, but I think she is saying she has become one with the wind.

On the other hand, で in 空いろ**で** is probably the te-form of だ. きっとわたしは空いろで would mean "I am perhaps sky blue (in color), and ...". That is, since she is in the sky, the sky has dyed her blue.

Another possibility is that 空いろで also modifies 運ばれる adverbially (in which case で is a case particle to mark a condition), but I cannot logically explain what "in a sky-blue manner" would mean.

In prosaic Japanese, those three lines would mean something like "こんな青い空の中(にいるので)、きっとわたしは空色をしている。そして、(わたしは)風のようになって運ばれる".

Comment: とても丁寧なご解説、ありがとうございます！The tricky part is that, even there are to words ending with で sticking together, they might modify different words...泣